# How to detect audio pulse and display frequency

Tags: android

[image: How to implement this using digimarc sdk]

I tried digimarc sdk but it display only pulse rather than colour pulse in image.help me if any other way for implement this.

Comment: What do you mean by audio pulse and display frequency?

Comment: I want to display sound pulse like above image when user want to record something.@RaduIonescu

Comment: I think you need to define what you consider audio pulse. Is it audio signal? And what do you mean by color pulse?

Comment: Audio pulse means voice spectrum and i want to generate color spectrum rather than CRT pulse.